# Actual physical RAM used by process

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

How can I determine actual physical RAM used by some process?

I can look into `/proc/PID/status` on `VmRSS` (or into `top`'s `RES` column). However, this number is incorrect for the processes which use multiple mappings backed by the same file. For example, the following piece of code maps several areas into a small physical memory window.

```
size_t window_size = ...; // e.g. 128 MiB
size_t total_size = ...;  // e.g. 4 TiB

char path[] = "/dev/shm/window-XXXXXX";

int fd = mkstemp(path);

ftruncate(fd, (off_t)window_size)

void *data = mmap(NULL, total_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);

for(ptrdiff_t offset = 0; offset < (ptrdiff_t)total_size; offset += window_size)
{
    mmap( (void *)( (uintptr_t)data + offset ), window_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED|MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
}
```

Now, if I look into `/proc/PID/status`, the kernel reports `VmRSS` as a sum of all the windows above. Although this number is even higher than the total physical memory size.

Comment: It's not even clear what "uses" mean. Imagine 9000 processes all map the same file to the same physical page. How would it count for each individual process? As 1 page or 1/9000 of a page?

Comment: @n.m.: Consider the code above. There is only one process which allocates, say, 4 TiB of virtual memory. However, only small fraction of this area resides in the physical memory.

In the case of pages shared by multiple processes, it does not matter which indicator I get -- the most pessimistic, the most optimistic one or anything in between.

Comment: But it's the same case actually. A file is mapped many times to the same physical page. What if all these processes are a part of the same program and you need to figure out how much memory the program takes? I faced this exact situation (the program in question was Apache spawning many processes). I ended up counting each individual physical page in kernel. I don't remember any details now. I think there was a kernel module dedicated to the task.

Comment: I figured it out.

Amount of the physical memory that process takes can be pretty well estimated as PSS (proportional set size) + PTE (page table entries size).

As I understand it, PSS indicates the count of pages in memory, where each page is divided by the number of shares. This value can be calculated as sum of all `Pss` rows in `/proc/PID/smaps`.

PTE is exposed in `/proc/PID/status` on the `VmPTE` line.

For the code above, I have got values like 1 GiB for PSS and another 1 GiB for PTE.